# How to extract (alphabet+number+underscore) before the dots using reg exp

Tags: php, regex

I wonder if there is a quick way using reg exp to extract what is before the vertical dots. I might use the explode but it will take long processing.

Sample string cases:

```
1. $str = 'a.b({ _first7 :1, second:2});';
2. $str = ' _first7 :1, second:2});';  // no bracket before _first7, and there is a space
3. $str = ' second:2});';
```

I need to get _first7 and second in cases (1,2) and just second in case 3.

I tried to extract between { and : for _first7 and it works but for case #2 it doesn't work. And I tried to extract between , and : to get second and it works but for case #3 it doesn't work.

like this:

```
$result = preg_match('/\{([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)\:/', $str, $output);
$result = preg_match('/\,([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)\:/', $str, $output);
```

Also, I don't know how to merge both expressions to get _first7, second,... n var all together in array and process them?

Your help with a complete solution is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Vertical dots? The name (in English) of : is _colon_. There may be a way to do this with a single regexp, but you'll probably have to use multiple regexps to do it. It will be easier to understand and maintain with multiple simpler regexps, anyway, and the code _might_ even be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're looking for the keys of the key-value pairs.

```
/[a-z0-9_]+(?=\s*:)/i
```

Should do it.

Comment: It works perfect! Never expected such a small line will do that magic! Appreciate your help! I used preg_match_all

Answer (score 1):

A pattern like this should work:

```
(\w+)\s*:
```

But you'll have to extract the first capture group. For example:

```
$str = 'a.b({ _first7 :1, second:2});';
$result = preg_match_all('/(\w+)\s*:/', $str, $output);
print_r($output[1]);
// Array ( [0] => _first7 [1] => second )
```

Alternatively you can use a lookahead:

```
\w+(?=\s*:)
```

For example:

```
$str = 'a.b({ _first7 :1, second:2});';
$result = preg_match_all('/\w+(?=\s*:)/', $str, $output);
print_r($output[0]); 
// Array ( [0] => _first7 [1] => second )
```

Comment: Yes the second one is working but the first one is giving a
b
_first7
1
second
2
third
5

Thank you a lot!

Comment: @moderns I'm not sure I understand your comment. What's the expected and actual output?

Comment: It is OK working perfect thanks I was seeing values of both elements in array. I can accredit only one answer as the correct answer and there is another correct answer before yours! Appreciate your help!

Comment: @moderns No problem. I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't any problem in the answer I posted. Glad I could help.